# Google measurement protocol transaction passing

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, measurement-protocol

I am making such request to Google Measurement API:

```
curl --request POST 'http://www.google-analytics.com/collect' --data "v=1&tid=UA-58879752-1&cid=1526087851.1425399573&t=transaction&dh=somedomain.com&ti=1&ta=clothing&tr=17.98&ts=2.0&tt=2.5&cu=EUR"
```

it returns me 1x1 GIF file:

```
GIF89a�����,D;%
```

But I don't see anything in transactions list:
[image]

Comment: it takes 24 - 48 hours for data to appear in the standard reports have you tried checking the real-time reports?

Comment: No, I didn't checked it. I don't see how to make transactions to be shown in real time.

Comment: I don't think you can see transactions real-time.  But you can send a different request to ensure that your code is working then check tomorrow to be sure that you are storing transactions correctly.

Comment: events are passing successfully in real-time view

Comment: then you should be ok.  wait 24 hours then check your transactions.  It takes Google time to process the data.  If your site is a small one you may see data sooner.    It depends upon how much data your site gets.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I see transactions. Can you write answer and I will rate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It takes 24 - 48 hours for data to appear in the standard reports, this is because Google needs time to process things.

You can check real-time reports but only send basic data.  This will tell you if your hits are in fact being recorded.

You will have to wait until tomorrow to see if the transaction data is being recorded that isn't available though the Real-time reports.

Comment: Yep, it's a pain to test Transaction hits.